# NV-GLX missing extension in OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, remote-access, xlib, glx

I connect to a remote linux machine using "ssh -X machine", and then I run a graphical application, so its window is displayed on my local OS X Lion machine using X Window. I get the error

"Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display "localhost:11.0"."

The application moves very slow. Is it any way to use NV-GLX on OS X or to cimcurvent this problem?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://severfault.com

Comment: unfortunately not, sorry and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered similar problem trying to connect from a laptop with AMD graphical card to a linux server with NVIDIA card and drivers installed.

If you have root access to your remote linux machine you could try to restart X server with default `libglx.so`, not the one from NVIDIA driver package. Appears that NVIDIA installer doesn't support partial installation (only driver, no GLX lib), so one needs to remove NVIDIA `libglx.so` from xorg modules path, but leave `nvidia_drv.so`. On Debian you could do

```
# update-alternatives --config glx # select mesa-diverted
# ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia/current/nvidia_drv.so /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/
```

Be shure your remote /etc/Xorg.0.log has following parts

```
...
[  1111.390] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1111.390] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1111.390] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
...
[  1111.391] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  1111.391] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[  1111.392] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
...
```

After that `Xlib: extension "NV-GLX" missing on display "localhost:11.0"` message should go away

Comment: Dang, I was hoping there was some way to configure the GLX without redoing the drivers. I don't have root access to the machine. Bounty awarded because you provided a solution. Thanks.